# How to solve the constraint nonlinear least-square problem?

Tags: optimization

[image]

I read a paper which says it can be solved by Gauss-Newton type method:
[image]

I cannot understand why bsin(theta) appears.It seems so starange.
Also it is very kind of you to recommend some math books to solve the problem above.

Comment: Is there anybody coming to help me ?! please...